# Determine if value exists in an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

Trying to determine if a value exists in an array like this:

```
$course_id = 1;

$sessions_query = $db->prepare("SELECT session_id FROM sessions WHERE course_id=:course_id");
$sessions_query ->bindValue(':course_id', $course_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sessions_query ->execute();
$sessions = $sessions_query ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$session_id = 1;

if (in_array($session_id, $sessions['session_id'])) {
    echo "Valid session";
}
else {
    echo "Invalid session";
}
```

I know that the value 1 is in the sessions['session_id'] array because when I echo the array I can see that value. However, the function is still returning "invalid session". Is this not the correct way to use the in_array function?

Comment: `->fetch()` reurns **1** row. You need to do that in a loop to create an array, or use `->fetchAll()` and check that array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`->fetch()` always returns one row, hence you'll have to loop through each `session_id`. You would do something like this:

**Edited:efficient approach**

Suppose your `sessions` table has 1000 entries and your `$session_id` matches with the 1st entry in the table. In this case the `while()` loop will not evaluate 1000 times, when a match is found, it'll break out from the loop.

```
$course_id = 1;

$sessions_query = $db->prepare("SELECT session_id FROM sessions WHERE course_id=:course_id");
$sessions_query ->bindValue(':course_id', $course_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sessions_query ->execute();

$session_id = 1;

$session_value_exists = false;
while($sessions = $sessions_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if ($session_id == $sessions['session_id'])) {
        $session_value_exists = true;
        break;    
    }
}
if($session_value_exists){
    echo "valid session";
}else{
    echo "invalid session";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As [`PDOStatement::fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) returns a single row, you need to loop over your returned set to create an array first.

```
$course_id = 1;

$sessions_query = $db->prepare("SELECT session_id FROM sessions WHERE course_id=:course_id");
$sessions_query ->bindValue(':course_id', $course_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sessions_query ->execute();
$sessions = array();
while($row = $sessions_query ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $sessions[] = $row['session_id'];
}

$session_id = 1;

if (in_array($session_id, $sessions)) {
    echo "Valid session";
}
else {
    echo "Invalid session";
}
```

Comment: It's not an efficient method to search. Suppose `sessions` table has 1000 entries and user's `session_id` matches the 1st entry, even in this case also the `while()` loop will evaluate 1000 times. Rather when a match is found, it should break from the loop.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul you are correct. In this situation it might be negligible, as if there was 1000 people in a `course`, I might look to transfer to a different school class.

Comment: in that case I would definitely move to another school. :)